# How does SimpleMembershipProvider.EncryptPassword work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, password-encryption

I am building an application that use SimpleMembershipProvider. I have to write something about how creating a new user works. Now I have to write about encrypting the password (and add the citation).

When I create a new user, I just use  WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount method. It automatically stores user and his password into the database, and it also encrypts his password.

What mechanism is used here? I cannot find anything on the internet about that.

Is Rfc2898DeriveBytes class used?

Comment: You can read the source http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that if you go through the callstack, you will eventually end up in [`SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateAccount(string, string, bool)`](https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs)

This method calls `string hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(password);` where `Crypto` is a helper class.

[This method](https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/Crypto.cs#L88) looks like the following:

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }

    // Produce a version 0 (see comment above) password hash.
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] subkey;
    using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, PBKDF2IterCount))
    {
        salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
        subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
    }

    byte[] outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SaltSize);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SaltSize, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
}
```

I believe this should answer your question.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: the github repo I linked had its last update 3 years ago, I think it's just a clone of the codeplex repo. I looked for the appropriate sources on https://github.com/aspnet but couldn't find it.